# centering background image when using transform 3d and positions relative and absolute

Tags: html, css

working on a web page (Codepen [here][1]) that has a header, a background image, and then some text. When you click on the image, it flips several times (spins on axis) to reveal a new image. I have been fighting with positioning this image for some time now. I finally have it to where the image is below the header and above the text, the spinning works, and the image stays in place while spinning.

The problem is I can't center the image. I want the image and the page itself to be responsive so the image is always in the center of the corridor it's in. Here is my HTML and CSS (the jQuery doesn't matter on this one):`

```
<h1>A Tribute to the Doctors of Doctor Who</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="card">
      <div class="front"></div>
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum (full paragraph)</p>

#container{
  width: 41vmin;
  height: 60vmin;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 3000px;       
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#card{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform-origin: center;
}

#card.flipped{
  transform: /*translateY(100%)*/ rotateY(900deg);
}

#card div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front{
  background-image: url("https://static3.comicvine.com/uploads/original/4/49017/1112141-tardis.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.back{
  background-image: url("https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c8/3a/ce/c83ace6e2751a862d21d48c59d63a780.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things - messing with margins, putting in left and top, taking out and changing the position absolutes and relatives. One thing I found out was that if I take the position: absolute off the #card div, the image will not stay in place when it spins.

This is driving me nuts! Help!!!

```
  [1]:
```

http://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/EmbPqr

Answer (score 1):

Just add another div outside of the div container and put a width:100%; and a text-align: center; and that should do it. I added the div and styles.

```css
.outside-container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside-container">
<div id="container">
  <div id="card">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLd6ep1t/)

Comment: I tried voting for your answer, but I don't have a high enough reputation yet.